# Error with plotting: "Error in do.call("constructMargin", margin) : second argument must be a list"

Tags: r-raster, levelplot

I am using levelplot to make a raster layer of my precipitation data, as shown below. Oddly enough, when I ran the following code previously, it went through just fine, but now, without any change made to the code, I have been experiencing a strange error, and there is little known about it online. Here is what I have done:

```
library(raster)
library(maptools)
library(rasterVis)
library(sp)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(RColorBrewer)


FPrec <- brick(Fncfname,var="fivedaymax") #making a raster brick
Fr <- abs(init(raster(), 'y'))
Fsm <- mean(FPrec, na.rm=TRUE) #calculates the mean into a raster layer
Fw <- init(FPrec, 'y')
Fw <- cos(Fw*(pi/180)) #creates weights to account for grid cell size 
discrepancies
Fx <- Fsm*Fw #applying the weights to each grid cell
FmapTheme <- rasterTheme(region=rev(brewer.pal(10,"Spectral")))
cutpoints <- c(200,175,150,125,100,75,50,25,0)
levelplot(Fx,margin=F,at=cutpoints,cuts=11,pretty=TRUE,par.settings=FmapTheme, main="Test variable 
for CanESM2")
```

The "levelplot" is where the problem occurs. I receive the following error:

```
Error in do.call("constructMargin", margin) : second argument must be a list
```

The object "Fsm" has the following attributes:

```
Fsm

class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 64, 128, 8192  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 2.8125, 2.789327  (x, y)
extent     : -181.4062, 178.5938, -89.25846, 89.25846  (xmin, xmax, ymin, 
ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1.949589, 627.0804  (min, max)
```

What could be causing this seemingly random error? I tried running the same thing in other versions of R (or in a new workspace), but the same problem occurs. It's something in levelplot that is causing it, but I cannot see anything obvious, especially since this code worked just fine previously).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please make your code minimal, reproducible, and self-contained (create the RasterLayer with code). . You surely do not need 11 packages to illustrate this problem? .

Comment: @Robert Hijmans - thank you for the response. I edited my original post to minimize the amount of code. However, a reproducible example would not necessarily lead to the same error in question (i.e. I cannot reproduce the error)?

Comment: You should be able to make an example that does reproduce the error. If not, that should be important too. Why not? To find out where and why this happens you need to remove the clutter. You need to provide code that creates `Fx` in one or two lines. You should use levelplot with only the defaults (not `par,settings`, `main`, etc).

Comment: @Robert Hijmans - I actually found the problem. It was simply an artifact of object name assignment. I think an object name I accidentally selected conflicted with an actual function, so when the code was run, it upset things beyond it, with levelplot being most sensitive. So, when levelplot was reached, the error resulted, and the error was permanent to any levelplot, as well as any levelplot that was working correctly previously. The only way to fix it was to shut down R, restart and select another object name in place of the one that was causing the issue, and then run everything again.